# How to get Numpy array of Canvas data?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am building an application with Tkinter, where one is able to draw e.g. lines in a Canvas. This works well. However, I'm unable to find a method for getting the current Canvas data. Preferably I would like to get a numpy array out of the current Canvas data, since my post-processing steps are mostly using numpy.

Is there any way to build numpy arrays out of the Canvas data? In some color format like RGB, by preference?

---

I know that I can get the information e.g. of lines (like coordinates) out of the Canvas, but I do not need this information. I need a **rasterized image data of the whole Canvas scene**. Like a numpy array or a (rasterized) image (jpg, png, tiff, bitmap, ...).

Comment: I've never used numpy, but methods to get coordinates from canvas items is well documented.

Comment: Yes, but I need image data, like a data array, or some image file (like jpg, png, tiff, bitmap, ...) out of the Canvas. The coordinates of the objects itself are irrelevant to me, because with just the coordinates I would have to redraw the scenery, for example with PIL. I need rasterized image data.

Comment: There is no way to get rasterized image data off of the canvas

Comment: I would say this is a design flaw? However, I have implemented a workaround. I saw that Canvas offers to save its contents in postscript format and since I am working a lot with SciPy (especially NumPy) I knew of scikit-image, which can read a lot of different image formats. I've posted an answer for anyone who might be interested: Canvas -> .eps-file on disk -> scikit-image data -> .png-file on disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Bryan Oakley said: there is **no** way to get a rasterized version of a Tkinter Canvas drawing.

However, I figured out this workaround:

```
import skimage.io as ski_io

(...)
# draw your canvas
(...)

# save canvas to .eps (postscript) file
canvas.postscript(file="tmp_canvas.eps",
                  colormode="color",
                  width=CANVAS_WIDTH,
                  height=CANVAS_HEIGHT,
                  pagewidth=CANVAS_WIDTH-1,
                  pageheight=CANVAS_HEIGHT-1)

# read the postscript data
data = ski_io.imread("tmp_canvas.eps")

# write a rasterized png file
ski_io.imsave("canvas_image.png", data)
```

I do not really like workarounds, but `skimage` seems to be the fastest solution for reading postscript files and writing pngs.

[Scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/) is developed as a toolkit for [SciPy](https://www.scipy.org/), therefore it is working with `scipy.ndimage` internally, which is exactly what I want and can be used to create `np.ndarray` very easily.

Additionally scikit-learn is a powerful and fast image processing software itself, which can manipulate, read, and save various image formats.

Now you have the full choice: get a [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) `np.ndarray` out of Canvas data for further computations, manipulate the `scipy.ndimage` with SciPy/scikit-image or save the data, e.g. as a rasterized png, to disk.